# Touch only on non-transparent pixels of SKSpriteNode in Swift3

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, sprite-kit

I have sprite node over all screen, but images are only somewhere, not over all screen. How to set touch only on non transparent images or how to delete transparent pixels or something... Maybe use physicsBody? Thanks for help!

```
        node = SKSpriteNode()
        node.texture = SKTexture(imageNamed: "yes.png")
        node.name = "yes"
        node.size = self.frame.size
        node.position = CGPoint(x: 0, y: node.size.height)
        node.zPosition = 3

        self.addChild(node)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without seeing your picture it's quite hard to give you a clear answer other than what I assume your issue looks like.

You can use SKPhysicsBody to solve your issue by doing this.

```
let texture =  SKTexture(imageNamed: "yes.png")
let node = SKSpriteNode(texture: texture)

node.name = "yes"
node.size = self.frame.size
node.position = CGPoint(x: 0, y: node.size.height)
node.zPosition = 3
node.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(texture: texture, size: texture.size())
self.addChild(node)
```

You will need to configure your physics body as well in order to get the correct collision behaviour.

Comment: This help! Thanks! Can you please tell me, how to set this method to texture array (atlas) ?